# How to set minimum height of QListWidgetItem?

Tags: qt, qlistwidget, qlistview

How can I set the minimum height of a `QListWidgetItem`? I'm using `QListWidget::setItemWidget()` with a customized widget, and although I explicitly declared minimum height of my customized widget, those `QListWidgetItem`s still have a pretty low height attribute.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Use `setSizeHint` on the items.

```
void QListWidgetItem::setSizeHint ( const QSize & size )
```

This is the right method for telling the delegate how much screen it must preserve for the item.

Look at http://qt-project.org/doc/qt-4.8/qlistwidgetitem.html#setSizeHint

Comment: i saw setSizeHint but didn't expect that its the soltuion

Answer (score 15):

To set minimum height of each individual `QListWidgetItem` you can use `sizeHint()` function. For example, following code will set minimum height of all the `QListWidgetItem` to 30px..

```
int count = ui->listWidget->count();
for(int i = 0; i < count; i++)
{
  QListWidgetItem *item = ui->listWidget->item(i);
  item->setSizeHint(QSize(item->sizeHint().width(), 30));
}
```

Hope this helps..