# Set minimum row-height of QComboBox

Tags: qt, qcombobox, qstandarditem, minimum-size

I am trying to set the minimum height of the rows in the `QComboBox` dropdown menu without changing their width or the size of the `QComboBox` itself.

By default the width and height of the row items are calculated by its data.  To make the dropdown list resize to the width of the data I am calling

```
view()->setMinimumWidth(view()->sizeHintForColumn(0);
```

in the combobox's `::showPopup()`.

However, since I have different font sizes in rows, I would like to enforce a minimum height on each row.

I tried to use `setSizeHint` on each `QStandardItem` that is added in the first column to the rows but without success. I tried:

```
item->setSizeHint(QSize(item->sizeHint().width(), minHeight));
```

(https://stackoverflow.com/a/10749345/1981832)

But this lead to the dropdown menu not resizing to the data's width.

So, I tried to leave the width "unset". However, both

```
item->setSizeHint(QSize(QSize().width(), minHeight));
```

and

```
item->setSizeHint(QSize(0, minHeight));
```

did not work. Does anyone have an idea how I can enforce a minimum height on the rows of the `QComboBox` without messing up the automatic width calculation?

Comment: Your question is confusing, from what you point out I can understand that you want to establish a fixed height, am I correct? I do not understand what you mean with a minimum height, minimum with respect to what?

Comment: @eyllanesc Each item in the dropdown list has a certain font set to it (think wordprocessor style chooser: heading 1, heading 2, etc.). Now, some of the font sizes in the list can be tiny. To make it possible to still easily choose them, I want to set the minimum height of a row to the standard row height (with the default UI font). So, yes, I want to fix the row height for these items. But I still want the items with larger fonts to have a greater height. That's why I was saying that I want each row to have a minimum height.

Comment: @eyllanesc Currently, I just manually check whether a font size of an item is greater than the default font size and then fix the minimum height only if it is smaller. I am not sure that's the best way to achieve this. But the main problem is that I cannot set a fixed height without messing up the automatic width calculation.

Comment: From what I understand: 1) Do you want to set a predefined fixed height for each row? That is, each row could have different heights. 2) That minimum height depends on the fonts, am I correct?

Comment: @eyllanesc Sounds right.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just use this lines:

```
QComboBox combo;
QListView *view = new QListView(&combo);
view->setStyleSheet("QListView::item{height: 100px}");
combo.setView(view);
```

Or write this code in `qss` file:

```
QListView::item {
    height: 30px;
}
```

After that use:

```
QComboBox::setView(QAbstractItemView *itemView)
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer. I am not using a `QListView` but just a layout model set via `setModel`. Should the solution work there as well? Also, is there a particular point at which the stylesheet has to be set?

Comment: Okay, got it to work with a style sheet. The important ingredient for my specific situation was to use `QStyledItemDelegate` instead if `QStyledItemDelegate` and then `QComboBox QAbstractItemView::item {min-height: 30px;}`.